# Let $ a \in F[x] \ $ be such that $ a | bc \ \Rightarrow either \ \ a | b \ \ or \ \ a | c \ $ , then show that $ \ a \ $ is irreducible polynomial

Tags: field-theory

Let $ a \in F[x] \ $ be such that $ a | bc \ \Rightarrow  either \ \ a | b \ \ or \ \ a | c \ $ ,  then show that $ \ a \ $ is irreducible polynomial in $ \ F[x] \ $. (Converse of Euclid theorem)

**Answer:**

If $ a |bc \ $ , then $ bc=ak , \ $ for some $ \ k \in F[x] \ $ .

Now let $ a|b \ $ , then $ \ b=ad , \ \ d \in F[x] \ $

Now,

$ b=ad \\ \Rightarrow bk=akd \\ \Rightarrow bk=bca , \ (\because bc=aj) \\ \Rightarrow k=ca \ ? \ $

But I don't know whether  $ \ F[x] \ $ is an integral domain or not.

**Alternate method:**

If $ F \ $ is a field , then $ F[x] \ $ is  a PID.

Now $ \ a|bc \ \Rightarrow either a|b \ \ or \ \ a |c \ $ shows that $ \ a \ $  is  prime.

In PID  , prime=irreducible.

Thus , $ a \in F[x] \ $ is irreducible.

**Am I right ?**

**If not, then help me out.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in a principal ideal domain, irreducible and prime elements are the same. But the point of the question is to prove one of these implications
(the easier one), namely that if $a(x)$ is prime then $a(x)$ is irreducible. If $a(x)=f(x)g(x)$ then $a(x)\mid f(x)g(x)$, so $a(x)\mid f(x)$ or $a(x)\mid g(x)$. In the former case $f(x)=a(x)h(x)=f(x)g(x)h(x)$
(for some polynomial $h(x)$), and as $F[x]$ is an integral domain ($F$ 
is a field) then $g(x)h(x)=1$, so $g(x)$ is a unit. Therefore $a(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: But if $ \ F \ $ be simply a ring , then what will happen? Can we still prove the result? Because I am not sure whether F is field or not.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is reducible then $a=mn$, where neither $m$ nor $n$ is unity. Now let $b=mk$ and $c=nl$, such that $n\nmid k$ and $m\nmid l$. Then $a\mid bc$ but $a\nmid b$ and $a\nmid c$.

Comment: Why not simplylet $b=m$, $c=n$?

Comment: that would have done too.